# Can't enable actuator into spring cloud gateway Greenwich

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, api-gateway

I just installed a **Spring Cloud Gateway server** (`Greenwich.SR2`) with **Boot Actuator starter** dependency, but can't reach any `/actuator/gateway` or `/gateway` API

I tried to activate and publish the endpoint, without success :

```
management.endpoint.gateway.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,gateway
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I acknowledge that this is a **WebFlux+Netty server**, but this is not supposed to make any difference from what I read. I must have missed something, though.

Any experience to share, someone?

Comment: Note that /actuator endpoint is alive :
{
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator",
"templated": false
},
"health": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/health",
"templated": false
},
"health-component-instance": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/health/{component}/{instance}",
"templated": true
},
"health-component": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/health/{component}",
"templated": true
},
"gateway": {
"href": "http://localhost:8090/actuator/gateway",
"templated": false
}
}
}

Comment: What are your routes

Comment: What does can't reach mean?

Comment: Thanks for your guidelines, it took me some time to realize that the root endpoint is blank and that I had to go on with API syntax

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, here goes the shame moment...

There is no API at `/actuator/gateway`; the API is at `/actuator/gateway/routes` and so on!

Comment: No shame, I was struggling with it for few hours. In the tutorial baeldung wrote "Once the Actuator API is installed and configured, the gateway monitoring features can be visualized by accessing /gateway/ endpoint." which is false because that endpoint returns 404. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Not just baeldung, if you see the actuator endpoint output, even there the path is just /actuator/gateway without 'routes', is this a bug?